# c++17 correct moving resource between unique_ptr in containers

Tags: c++, c++17, move, unique-ptr, emplace

How to correct move resource from existed unique_ptr to another created in container?
I want to put to container some unique_ptr with resource from another unique_ptr. Or maybe move one unique_ptr from one container to another container.

Some code with creation is here:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct MyClass
{
    std::string s;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, MyClass> container;
    
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> tmp = std::make_unique<MyClass>();
    tmp->s = "test string";

    auto result = container.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::make_tuple("test"),
        std::make_tuple(std::move(tmp))
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot move the object itself to be held by the map, but in your case the members of `MyClass` are movable and thus `MyClass` will be movable. So you will get a new Object of type `MyClass` and I am aware of no mechanism to retain the object and have it be managed by the map instead of the unique_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

Your map holds `MyClass`, but you are trying to move a `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>` into it.

You need to get the instance from your `std::unique_ptr` and move that.

```
std::make_tuple(std::move(*tmp))
                          ^___ Dereference the unique_ptr
```

Comment: error `message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tuple<MyClass> std::make_tuple<MyClass>(MyClass &&)' being compiled`

Comment: @Pasha [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/bETv8o46T).

Comment: That is in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: `1>Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\tuple(890,18): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from '_Ty' to '_Ttype'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=MyClass
1>        ]
1>Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\tuple(888,1): message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>test.cpp(144): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tuple<MyClass> std::make_tuple<MyClass>(MyClass &&)' being compiled`

Comment: You sure are a stubborn one huh... ? It compiles fine with [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/oxc814EGW) as well. You probably have something more in your code that makes `MyClass` non-movable... if I had to guess. The point I'm trying to get across here is that I shouldn't have to guess. Update your question with a proper [mre].